# how to make chrome start on startup in tablet mode

Tags: windows-10, windows-tabletpc, tablet-mode

I followed these [instructions](https://www.solveyourtech.com/how-to-start-google-chrome-automatically-when-computer-starts/). Now when I start the computer in regular (desktop mode) it works, chrome launches.

I need it to work in tablet mode though. And it doesn't.

When I start in tablet mode and switch to desktop, chrome launches, not by itself in tablet mode.